# getting multiple parameters separately (C# discord bot 0.9.6)

Tags: c#, discord

So what I'm trying to do is that I want my bot to be able to have two different parameters. Like what I mean is something like I can extract like a certain part of it and then after there's a "," or another symbol I can extract the following separately. So I get two different strings from one input. So like I have two strings and I want one of them to be the first half and the second one to be the rest. And I am not planning on updating to 1.0 so tell me if it's not possible in 0.9.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question isn't very clear but I think I know what you are looking for.  This is a general answer for C# as I don't know how the Discord interface differs.  You seem to be taking input in the form of a string, for example: `play *songname*,*channelname*`.  To split this string into two inputs you want to use `String.Split(',')`
An example would be this:

```
string stringTakenFromDiscord = "play *songname*,*channelname*";
String[] input = stringTakenFromDiscord.Split(',');

//input[0] will be equal to what comes before the comma
//if you were to print it, it would be "play *songname*"

//input[1] will be  what comes after the comma
//if you were to print it, it would be "*channelname*"
```

Now you can do anything you want with either of the values of the array `input[]` and feed them through your code to parse them.  Do note that when it splits by the character, the character won't appear in either of the output strings.  This will only work for inputs that only have one instance of your chosen character.  You can change the character to whatever you want.

It occurs to me that it might be easier to just take the input on two separate lines instead.